# Error Using pandas with arima

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to get the hang of working with arima models in python.  I've tried using the code from statsmodel and pandas below.  But I'm getting the "ValueError: Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates" error below.  I found another post mentioning the same error where they changed the dataframe to a matrix using as_matrix, I tried it but it didn't solve my problem.  I just got a new numpy array error.  Any tips would be very much appreciated.  I have a lot more experience doing this in r, but r has plenty of headaches when dealing with time-series too.

sample data descirption:

```
y.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4347 entries, 0 to 4346
Data columns (total 2 columns):
lastSaleDate      4347 non-null datetime64[ns]
lastSaleAmount    4347 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 68.0 KB


Sample Data:
   lastSaleDate  lastSaleAmount
1    1997-08-13   102900.000000
2    1997-08-14    84833.333333
3    1997-08-15    26171.000000
4    1997-08-19   167000.000000
5    1997-08-20   107500.000000
6    1997-08-21   175000.000000
7    1997-08-25    56000.000000
8    1997-08-26    74300.000000
9    1997-08-28   118500.000000
10   1997-08-29   305333.333333
11   1997-09-02    50000.000000
12   1997-09-03   116950.000000
13   1997-09-04    58000.000000
14   1997-09-08    72250.000000
15   1997-09-10    60000.000000
16   1997-09-12    75000.000000
17   1997-09-15    57700.000000
18   1997-09-18    21000.000000
19   1997-09-19    47500.000000
20   1997-09-22    49900.000000
21   1997-09-23    81750.000000
22   1997-09-25    57000.000000
23   1997-09-26    69000.000000
24   1997-09-29   396000.000000
25   1997-09-30   213500.000000
26   1997-10-01   152500.000000
27   1997-10-02    99666.666667
28   1997-10-03    83000.000000
29   1997-10-06    84500.000000
30   1997-10-07   157000.000000
31   1997-10-15   272000.000000
32   1997-10-16    45900.000000
33   1997-10-17    68500.000000
34   1997-10-20   108000.000000
35   1997-10-21    66800.000000
36   1997-10-22   115633.333333
37   1997-10-24    62015.000000
38   1997-10-27   113000.000000
39   1997-10-28    41000.000000
40   1997-10-31   114950.000000
41   1997-11-03    71000.000000
42   1997-11-07    20500.000000
43   1997-11-13    68500.000000
44   1997-11-17    65000.000000
45   1997-11-18    94900.000000
46   1997-11-19    89900.000000
47   1997-11-21   213833.333333
48   1997-11-24    63300.000000
49   1997-11-25   227825.000000
```

Code:

```
lag=y['lastSaleAmount'].shift()

mod = sm.tsa.ARIMA(endog=y['lastSaleAmount'],exog=lag,order=[1,1,0])

results = mod.fit()

print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-0120f3323d31> in <module>()
     11 #y=y.as_matrix()
     12 
---> 13 mod = sm.tsa.ARIMA(endog=y['lastSaleAmount'],exog=lag,order=[1,1,0])
     14 
     15 results = mod.fit()

/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.pyc in __new__(cls, endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)
    963         else:
    964             mod = super(ARIMA, cls).__new__(cls)
--> 965             mod.__init__(endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)
    966             return mod
    967 

/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.pyc in __init__(self, endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)
    973             # in the predict method
    974             raise ValueError("d > 2 is not supported")
--> 975         super(ARIMA, self).__init__(endog, (p, q), exog, dates, freq, missing)
    976         self.k_diff = d
    977         self._first_unintegrate = unintegrate_levels(self.endog[:d], d)

/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.pyc in __init__(self, endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)
    443     def __init__(self, endog, order, exog=None, dates=None, freq=None,
    444                  missing='none'):
--> 445         super(ARMA, self).__init__(endog, exog, dates, freq, missing=missing)
    446         exog = self.data.exog  # get it after it's gone through processing
    447         _check_estimable(len(self.endog), sum(order))

/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.pyc in __init__(self, endog, exog, dates, freq, missing)
     40     def __init__(self, endog, exog=None, dates=None, freq=None, missing='none'):
     41         super(TimeSeriesModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing)
---> 42         self._init_dates(dates, freq)
     43 
     44     def _init_dates(self, dates, freq):

/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.pyc in _init_dates(self, dates, freq)
     49             if (not datetools._is_datetime_index(dates) and
     50                     isinstance(self.data, data.PandasData)):
---> 51                 raise ValueError("Given a pandas object and the index does "
     52                                  "not contain dates")
     53             if not freq:

ValueError: Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates
```

Comment: try to set your datecolumn as the index before defining the lag etc.. `y = y.set_index('lastSaleDate')`

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Thank you!  That worked.  Previously I had it set as the index but I was getting an error about no time data field.  That's why I turned it into a date with pd.to_datetime, but it looks like I had to turn it back in to an index.  Do you know why it needed to be turned back in to an index?

Comment: In your error message you can see that it's an requirement for the statsmodel of if you use pandas dataframes. `Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates` which implies that you should give it a dataframe/series where the indes contains dates or datetimes.